# How to ship Airflow logs to Azure Blob Store

Tags: azure, logging, blob, airflow, log-shipping

I'm having trouble following [this guide](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/airflow/v1-10-test/airflow.pdf) section 3.6.5.3 "Writing Logs to Azure Blob Storage"

The documentation states you need an active hook to Azure Blob storage.  I'm not sure how to create this.  Some sources say you need to create the hook in the UI, and some say you can use an environment variable.  Either way, none of my logs are getting written to blob store and I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Blob Store hook(or any hook for that matter) tells overflow how to write to into Azure Blob Store. This is already included in recent versions of airflow, [wasb_hook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/wasb_hook.py).

You will need to make sure that the hook is able to write to Azure Blob Store. Just mention the `REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER` bucket should be named like `wasb-xxx`. Once you take care of these two things [instructions](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/write-logs.html) works without a hitch,

Comment: So I would put a file in my DAG bag which creates a wasb_hook that uses the connection id I specify in Airflow.  If I have an environment variable AIRFLOW_CONN_AZURE_LOGGING set to the wasb url of my container, I would set the logging hook's wasb_conn_id property to "azure_logging" correct?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved writing logs to blob using below steps

1. Create folder named `config` inside airflow folder
2. Create empty `__init__.py` and `log_config.py` files inside `config` folder
3. Search `airflow_local_settings.py` in your machine

/home/user/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py
/home/user/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.pyc

run

```
cp /home/user/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py config/log_config.py
```

4. Edit `airflow.cfg` [core] section

`remote_logging = True`

`remote_log_conn_id = log_sync`

`remote_base_log_folder=wasb://airflow-logs@storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/logs/`

`logging_config_class =log_config.DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG`

5. Add `log_sync` connection object as below
   [image]

6. install airflow azure dependency

   `pip install apache-airflow[azure]`
7. Restart webserver and scheduler